# How to define default open file location for rich:fileUpload?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using rich:fileUpload to upload files.

When i click the + button to add a file, the default location of the file browser is the last
location i visited with the windows file browser.

How can i set the default location that the file browser showld open when clicking on the + button?

Isn't there some thing similar to the HTML: <input type="file" value="DEFAULT PATH" />  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INMO **you can't** modify the location of the file browser not in `rich:fileUpload` and not in any file upload component, unless you build your own flash based or some other custom file upload component that wont use the browser native one, *since the server never knows the file structure of the client machine*

You can take a look at similar threads on google: [default path to open location in file upload](https://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1C1CHEU_enIL465IL465&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=default%20path%20to%20open%20location%20in%20file%20upload)